# How to create an infinite scrollable loop for slotmachine JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So a while back I implemented the a slot machine library to my site. My intention was allowing the user to infinitely scroll through the icons like a slot machine. Though I cant figure out how to do it like the documentation/library website has it. My site rather goes back up, going past all the other icons rather than being infinite scroll like.

**What I have:** https://gyazo.com/a265ec86bce7316098232608e723cadf

**What I want:**
https://gyazo.com/0f592ae2ce8c7951aa2b9095faafb01e

**Example Code:**

```js
// Set up previous button
const btnPrev = document.querySelector('#prev');

// Set up Next Button
const btnNext = document.querySelector('#next');

// Set up our container
const el = document.querySelector('#theContainer');

// Create new SlotMachine
const slot = new SlotMachine(el, {});

// Add Event Listeners or do things when we click it
btnPrev.addEventListener('click', () => slot.prev());
btnNext.addEventListener('click', () => slot.next());
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-slotmachine@4.0.0/dist/jquery.slotmachine.min.css">
</style>

<div id="theContainer" class="container" style="width: 100px; height: 100px">
  <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/?image=0"></div>
  <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/?image=1"></div>
  <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/?image=2"></div>
</div>
<button id="prev">Previous</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>

<!-- Add script files -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-slotmachine@4.0.0/dist/slotmachine.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: have and want are the same

Comment: @kallosz exactly thats why im a bit lost what im doing wrong

Comment: @kallosz SORRY Fixed :)